# Arbitrary correspondence between vertical axes

Tags: plotting, labeling, logarithmic-scale, scaling

I am doing boxed contour plots of a quantity that depends on two variables. Let's call it f[A,B]. A will go to the lower horizontal axis, and B to the left vertical axis. I would like the two remaining axes (call them C and D) to follow known rules, i.e. the right vertical will be some known function of the left vertical axis: D=D(B), and similarly for the upper horizontal axis: C=C(A).
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f, g, h]
f[x_, y_] := Cos[x] + Cos[y]
d[x_] := 5 + 2 x
c[x_] := Log[5 x]
```

You can use `` Charting`ScaledTicks[{d, InverseFunction[d]}] `` to construct the ticks for the right axis and `` Charting`ScaledTicks[{c, InverseFunction[c]}] `` for the top axis:

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks[{d, InverseFunction[d]}][##] &},  
    {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks[{c, InverseFunction[c]}][##] &}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @MCV, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. And welcome to mma.se.